# Stop promises execution once the first promise resolves

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, cancellation

I'm using ES6 promises, the idea of this function is to loop over an array of links, and for each link look for an image and stop once an image found.

In this case of the function that I wrote, the fastest promise resolves and others keeps executing, so what I want is to stop the execution of the remaining promises as soon as the first one resolves.

```
scrapImage(links) {
  let promises = links.map((l) => getImageUrlAsync(l));
  return Promise.race(promises);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What is it that you're actually trying to achieve? ES6 promises are not cancellable, but some third-party promise libraries (such as Bluebird) support cancellation.

Comment: I wanna stop the promises execution once the first one resolves, if that is not possible with es6 promises how I can achieve that?

Comment: No, the purpose isn't clear. _Why_ do you want to stop the promises' execution? What goal does that serve?

Comment: Lets say `getImageUrlAsync()` does a lot of work for each element of the array, isn't reasonable to stop execution of other promises for better performance once I have my result?

Comment: That would depend on whether the bulk of that work is likely to continue happening after the first promise has fully resolved or whether most of the work would be done by that point. I suggest running some benchmarks to make sure this isn't premature optimization. There is currently no standard approach to cancelling promises. [Here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html) is the document on cancellation in bluebird, and bluebird is a great library so if you really need cancellation, it would be a fine choice.

Comment: By the time you know you want to cancel the other promises, assuming `getImageUrlAsync` is an ajax call, the request has already been sent off and the server has started working on it. You can cancel the request, but that won't stop the server from continuing to work on it. If there is heavy overhead on the server side in processing the request, which you want to cancel you'll need some kind of special mechanism to alert the server to abort the processing. All in all, it doesn't seem worth the trouble except in special situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises don't "execute". They're return values, not functions. A promise is not a control-surface to whatever function returns one. Sounds like you want to cancel `getImageUrlAsync()`, so I would look for a cancellation API in whatever that API is.

Absent such a cancellation API, the best you can do is `Promise.race` on the array of promises, as you're doing. As others have pointed out, when things run in parallel, it may already be too late to recall the other launched actions.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's no way to stop execution
'cause all promises start at the same time when use Promise.race.

Try to use loop, eg [while](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-while).

Some sample code using ES7, if you are using babel.

```
async doSomething(links) {
  let l = links.length;
  while (l--) {
    let res = await getImageUrlAsync(links[l]);
    if (res) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```